# Manage Two Different Cache file in single cache folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching

I need a help to figure out one issue with the codeigniter caching.

I am running two functions to store a result in cache. This function is in my model :

```
public function cacheAllCurrencies()
    {
        $this->db->cache_on();
        $this->db->select("name,icon,currency_code");
        $this->db->from("currency");
        $this->db->where("status='Active'");
        $cache_currency_result = $this->db->get()->result();
        $this->db->cache_off();
        return $cache_currency_result;
    }

    public function cacheAllCategory()
    {
        $this->db->cache_on();
        $this->db->select("name,url");
        $this->db->from("category");
        $this->db->where("parent_category='0'");
        $this->db->where("status='Active'");
        $this->db->order_by('name','ASC');
        $cache_category_result = $this->db->get()->result();
        $this->db->cache_off();
        return $cache_category_result;
    }

My these two functions are called in header view like below :

$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model(PUBLIC_DIR.'/commonPage','common');
$currencies = $CI->common->cacheAllCurrencies();
$categories = $CI->common->cacheAllCategory();
```

Now, when all the page loads, it creates a cache file according to the page opened like home, blog, blog+blogname etc.

Both query generates two cache file in cache folder

`1580e4c2413cb09f6ed3bc7fae8cee45` - first function cache result
`d7e2452b0424f859e1a5984bd26cbd6c` - second function cache result

Now, I have two questions :

1. I need to delete 1580e4c2413cb09f6ed3bc7fae8cee45  cache file when I update currency table same for the category.
2. How this file name generated ? I mean how `codeigniter` generates cache file name. In my cache `1580e4c2413cb09f6ed3bc7fae8cee45` for currency and `d7e2452b0424f859e1a5984bd26cbd6c` for category.

I hope this explanation makes sense and I hope most of the `codeigniter` developer having this problem which need to be sort it out.

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: 2. Looks like an MD5.

Comment: @WillParky93 : Yes it seems that it is like md5. But what name is converted in to md5 ?

Comment: From [codeigniter](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/8186b6b398c26c0c1e0052eaddf4fc122e4929a5/system/core/Output.php) line 660, the cache is created from the full uri path

Comment: @WillParky93 : it is not the same what is run by these two queries

Comment: Sorry my bad; [line 135](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/362c0a14a987d6462e4062a5fc34099446f9e14f/system/database/DB_cache.php) says `An MD5 hash of the SQL statement will become the cache file name.`

Comment: @WillParky93 : I am still not getting this name what already have in my cache folder

Comment: I have no idea, I'm just going off the source I can find. look at what Kundan said tho, with his method you won't need to hash it yourself.

Comment: My concern is that, I need to delete the cache file when I update the relevant table. If I update currency table at that time all the currency cache should be deleted

Comment: Is the hash always the same or is it changing between every call?

Comment: @WillParky93 : yes..

Comment: They have never changed the naming method of caching, `$filename = md5($sql);` where $sql is your full query. Maybe when you tried you missed some part of your query?

Comment: @WillParky93 : according to my query, it will be like "select name,icon,currency_code from currency where status='Active' "

Comment: Was this the exact output of `$this->db->last_query();`?

Comment: $this->db->select("name,icon,currency_code");
        $this->db->from("currency");
  $this->db->where("status='Active'");
        $query =$this->db->get()->result();
  print $this->db->last_query();
  exit;
I am could not be able to print the query :(

Comment: Maybe don't use exit; and try a print_r() instead of print

Comment: another query is displaying rather than this query if I remove exit

Comment: What's being printed? If another query is being displayed then that's why we are not getting a matching md5 hash

Comment: another query of SELECT `avatar` FROM `customer` WHERE `id` = 2 which is run elsewhere

Comment: Try throwing a `$this->db->reset_query()` before your `$this->db->select(` call

Comment: SELECT `name`, `icon`, `currency_code` FROM `currency` WHERE `statu ts` = 'Active' this is the query output

Comment: Has the hash changed by any chance? I feel like it would have since it didn't register the query  output correctly. Also, is this correct? `WHERE statu ts = 'Active'` Shouldn't it be `status='Active'`

Comment: $file_name=md5($this->db->get_compiled_select());  it is the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Codeigniter**, you can clear the cache of DB using the table name
like

```
$this->db->cache_delete('currency');
$this->db->cache_delete('category');
```

OR two table cache at the same time

```
$this->db->cache_delete('currency','category');
```

**EDIT :**
CodeIgniter save filename by md5() encryption of SQL query

```
public function cacheAllCurrencies(){
    $this->db->cache_on();
    $this->db->select("name,icon,currency_code");
    $this->db->from("currency");
    $this->db->where("status='Active'");
    //here you get filename
    $file_name=md5($this->db->get_compiled_select());
    $cache_currency_result = $this->db->get()->result();
    $this->db->cache_off();
    return $cache_currency_result;
}
```

Comment: When I apply this code, it generates so many other cache files

Comment: but when apply your code it will give me this name "c374e48f9b2cf50386c051b6dbec427b" which is not correct

Comment: check **write()** function in  `system/database/DB_cache.php` may be ur ci diff version using diff logic to store cache file.

Comment: No, It is working now.. but can't do the same thing for another function. It gives Database error of No tables selected

Comment: Both are working fine. I need to run query in single line rather than multiple line :

$sql = $this->db->select('name,url')->from('category')->where("parent_category='0'")->where("status='Active'")->order_by('name','ASC')->get_compiled_select();;
  echo md5($sql);
  exit;
Then it will give me the exact name  :)